# Keyboard cover half of the screen in Overlay

Tags: react-native

I have a TextInput on an Overlay Component in my app. When the keyboard is opened, half the screen gets covered, including the TextInput. I did try the KeyboardAvoidingView component, but couldn't get the TextInput to be fully visible. I need some suggestion on how to move the components inside the Overlay, when the keyboard is enabled in react-native

Answer (score 0):

it wld have been easier to answer if u had posted code, but still

keyboardAvoidview solve the common problem of views that need to move out of the way of the virtual keyboard. It can automatically adjust either its position or bottom padding based on the position of the keyboard

just add this under your largest view

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.container} behavior="padding" enabled>
 all ur ui inside this...
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a prop called [keyboardVerticalOffset](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboardavoidingview#keyboardverticaloffset),
that is the distance between the top of the user screen and the react native view.

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.container} behavior="padding" enabled keyboardVerticalOffset={offsetValue}>
  ... your UI ...
</KeyboardAvoidingView>;
```

Value for **keyboardVerticalOffset** may be non-zero in some use cases. but for your case try to add some value.

If you want to know more about handling keyboard in react native [check this](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-make-your-react-native-app-respond-gracefully-when-the-keyboard-pops-up-7442c1535580/)